# Is it possible for several svelte pages and components to share the same +server.js file?

Tags: svelte

I have several standard svelte pages (in their own folders, +page.svelte files) and some components.

I have bundled some utility functions into a src/lib/scripts/utils.js file that are used by various pages and components.
Some of these functions interact with the +server.js file to do things like looking through folder hierarchies, creating json files etc.
The problem is that I have to copy the +server.js file into each page's directory for this to work.

Is it possible to have a global +server.js file, like my utils.js file ?
Perhaps possible to just refer to a server.js file sorted somewhere in each +server.js file ?
(Is it possible also to define a +server.js file for a component ?)

I tried putting a +server.js file in the scripts.
Tried importing this file into each +server.js file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`+layout.server.js`/`ts` file](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout-layout-server-js), which might be suitable for that. Like page layouts it will apply to all routes in the directory.

`+server.js` defines an endpoint that should be usable from anywhere, though. You just need to send the request to the correct URL; maybe it can just be parameterized accordingly so you can just use a single endpoint rather than many.